# How to create a mouseover effect on buttons in livecode?

Tags: livecode

I've been looking for a mouseover effect in LiveCode but I haven't got it yet.
I would like to get an effect somewhat like this link:
[Creating a Mouseover Fade Effect with jQuery](http://bavotasan.com/2009/creating-a-jquery-mouseover-fade-effect/)

This was created in jQuery. Can it be applied in LiveCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the fade-in/out you can accomplish the rollover effect without scripting. Simply import the two images, then set the icon property of a button to the id of one image and the hoverIcon property of the same button to id of the other image.

In terms of scripting rollover effects, Scott's answer is spot-on—you can use the mouseEnter and mouseLeave messages to create whatever visual change you want. If you need the fade-in/out effect this will do it:

-Create a new button, make it transparent, showName off, borders off.

-Import your two images. Let's say they are named image1 and image2.

-Set the script of the button to the following:

```
on mouseEnter
    set the effectRate to 500
    lock screen for visual effect
    set the icon of me to "image2"
    unlock screen with visual effect dissolve
end mouseEnter

on mouseLeave
    set the effectRate to 500
    lock screen for visual effect
    set the icon of me to "image1"
    unlock screen with visual effect dissolve
end mouseLeave
```

This creates an effect almost precisely like the one in the link you provided. You can change the rate of the dissolve effect by changing the effectRate; higher rate for slower dissolve, lower rate for faster dissolve. (The effectRate is in milliseconds.)

Comment: Thanks! I would try it as fast I can!

Answer (score 1):

mouseEnter (followed by mouseLeave) is pretty much the equivalent of mouseover in web technologies.  LiveCode doesn't have a built-in fade effect, but you can write your own by changing the blendLevel property of an object.  For example, add the following script to a button to make it fade out to 80% translucency on mouseEnter (mouseover), and fade back to opaque on mouseLeave:

```
on mouseEnter
   repeat with N = 0 to 80 step 5
      set blendLevel of me to N
   end repeat
end mouseEnter

on mouseLeave
   repeat with N = 80 to 0 step -5
      set blendLevel of me to N
   end repeat
end mouseLeave
```

Comment: It was not the expected effect, though it would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> `on mousewithin
>      put random(1000)
>   end mousewithin`

Comment: In the script of your button, graphic or other object, add the handler:

on mousewithin
   do what you would like
end mousewithin

While the users mouse is within the rect of the object, the script will be activated.